# Imagemagick - replace transparent pixel by black ones

Tags: linux, imagemagick, transparency

I have an image which contains some transparent pixels. I want to change the color of these pixels to black using imagemagick (or any line command tool).

The transparent pixels are not all of the same color so I can't just switch their color to black.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just found my answer...

I did not know that transparent pixels are considered as background so this works :

```
convert sourceimage.png -background black destinationimage.png
```

Comment: Transparent pixels are not "considered background" but since they are transparent underlaying a black layer does exactly what you need.